Print data for an object based on value(variable) for a key in jq output
I have this JSON :
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "agent": "23ef",
    "displayName": "foo.com"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "agent": "23gh",
    "displayName": "foo2.com"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "agent": "23gf",
    "displayName": "boo.com"
  }
]

Wanted to get the dataset for all objects which have foo in their displayName.
I am able to get when i pass the value as a string,
$ cat /tmp/z.json | jq -r '.[] | select(.displayName=="foo.com")'  {   "id": "1",   "agent": "23ef",   "displayName": "foo.com" }

But not getting when i try a regex. Can somebody help?
$ cat /tmp/z.json | jq -r '.[] | select(.displayName=="foo*")' 


For the |, don't you need sthg like xargs to pass value from one step to another?

Have a look at startswith or contains.

use this
cat /tmp/z.json | jq -r '.[] | select(.displayName | test("^foo"))'
== operator does not supported in regex pattern
hope this work for you !!

Thank you. Works like a charm.
Any idea how to pass a variable:
i=foo ; cat /tmp/z.json | jq -r '.[] | select(.displayName | test("${i}"))'
This ddnt return anything. :(
